# Rational Functions

Tags: graphing-functions, rational-functions

**Part 1**:
You are planning a school field trip that costs $120$ dollars to rent the bus.

A. How much will it cost per student if $10$ students go? $12$? $15$?

B. Write an equation to represent the cost per student if $x$ is the number of   students who sign up

C. Graph your equation, label the axes and asymptotes.

**Part Two**:
You find out it costs $7.25$ dollars per student admission to the program.

A. Write a new equation for the cost per student if $x$ is the number of students
 who sign up.

**Part Three**:
Two students drop out.

A. Write a new equation for the cost per student if $x$ is the number of students who signed up originally.

B. How many students need to go if the cost per student is to be under $15.00$ dollars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: Let $y$ be the cost per student, then $y = \dfrac{120}{x}$ whose graph is a hyperbola in the first quadrant with the $x$ axis and the $y$ axis as asymptotes. If $10$ students go, then $x = 10 \to y = 12$ dollars/student....